# Access minecraft rcon server via putty

Tags: ssh, console, putty, minecraft

I would like to manage Minecraft server by using built in rcon.

Problem is that the server doesn't return content.
open putty -> set address -> set port -> select ssh -> click open -> console opens, but its empty & i can't do anything.

The weird thing is that:
1. ports are open
2. in putty log shows this: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port xxxxx
3. minecraft console inform that im connected to the rcon

so it looks that I'm connected, but nothing shows in putty console.

I tried [this query tool](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/842376-minecraft-server-rconquery-utility/) and its work fine. If this tool can, why putty can't?

Thnx for any help.

Comment: What are your results with other SSH clients? It'd be nice to know if this is a PuTTy issue or on your server. Also, what happens if you type a command? You may not get any feedback at all until you try to do something.

Comment: I tried a lot of stuff before posting the question.
Other ssh clients like on my android also are connected, but with no visual response.
I cant type any command.

Comment: I'm sure you did try a lot of stuff, but we have no way of knowing what stuff you did and didn't try. If you type a command - even if the text isn't displayed - does the server obey it?

Comment: Yes, sorry.
I can't send any command from putty. After opening address i've got empty console with no ability to write/send anything and event log as shown [link](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/2557/puttyj.jpg).
I think server is listening because it inform me that someone is connecting via rcon. Also the query tool i've posted above can access rcon.
I don't know what more i could tell you so please ask questions. Thnx for -1 XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try [**mcrcon**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrcon/) which is specifically designed for Minecraft remote connections. Its quite easy to use and it supports bukkit console colors too.

Description from the website :

> **Description**
>
> Mcrcon is powerful IPv6 compliant minecraft rcon client with bukkit coloring support. It is well suited for remote administration and to be used as part of automated server maintenance scripts. Does not trigger "IO: Broken pipe" or "IO: Connection reset" spam bug on server side.
>
> Precompiled binaries available for Windows (x86), Linux (x86) and Mac OS X (x86 / x86-64).
>
> **Features**
>
> - IPv6 support.
> - Interactive terminal mode.
> - Support for Bukkit coloring on Windows and sh compatible shells.
> - Send multiple commands in one command line.
> - Silent mode. Does not print rcon output.
> - Does not cause "IO: Connection reset" spam on server side.
> - Designed to be used as part of the toolchain in server maintenance scipts.

Program homepage on **[Bukkit forums](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admin-rcon-mcrcon-remote-connection-client-for-minecraft-servers-new-ipv6-support.70910/)**.

Answer (score 5):

RCON is a specific protocol in the same way that SSH and Telnet are their own protocols. When you open a connection to Minecraft (or any application) running RCON - you need to talk RCON and not SSH / HTTP / Telnet.

You're currently (or were) trying to talk SSH to RCON, which won't work. If you change Putty to RAW mode, you could begin having a dialog with your Minecraft server, if you format your data packet correctly.

The Valve protocol is explained [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol)

Depending on what your end goal is, there are protocol wrappers for various programming languages out there... Java, PHP, .NET - only a Google away

Comment: How would one go about formatting their data packet correctly? I am interested in this too.

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol